# Remove tokens characters from NSString

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstring

I have a `NSTokenFiled` that validates the inserted tokens through the `-tokenField:shouldAddObjects:atIndex:` delegate method. Unfortunately this method is only called when the user presses the tokenizing character. When he/she clicks outside the control, presses esc or tab the unfinished string is automatically converted to a token without invoking the validation method.

After asking google I noticed that the problem is known and someone on stackoverflow suggested to override the `-control:isValidObject:` delegate method to validate the remaining string.

Unfortunately the object passed to this method is a `NSMutableString` with an invisible character for every token that has already been inserted in the token field. Probably this how cocoa keeps track of where to display tokens.

My question is: how can I remove those illegal characters?

So far I have tried these:

```
NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[stringWithInvisibleCharcters UTF8String]];

NSString *newString = [stringWithInvisibleCharacters stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet illegalCharacterSet]];

NSString *newString = [stringWithInvisibleCharacters stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet controlCharacterSet]];
```

With no success. I know that the last two would work only in the case where the tokens characters are at the beginning and at the end but that's my case so far.

**Edit:**

If it helps logging the characters with

```
NSLog(@"%hu",[(NSMutableString *)object characterAtIndex:0]);
```

returns 65532.

Comment: WHat do u mean by invalid Characters/?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The character associated with 65532 is known as the "Object Replacement Character", which appears to be out of the bounds of the Unicode range NSCharacterSet handles with it's getters.  Like you said, NSTokenField is using it as a delimiter between tokens.  Something like this to get rid of it should work just fine:

```
NSCharacterSet *characterset=[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\uFFFC"];
NSString *newString = [str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:characterset];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *str;  
NSCharacterSet *characterset=[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"];  
str = [str1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:characterset];`
```